# Retrieve the parents and children using HyperGraphQL

Tags: tree, graphql, ontology

I'm querying [go.owl](http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/go.owl) file containing the [Gene Ontology](http://geneontology.org/docs/download-ontology/) using [HyperGraphQL](https://www.hypergraphql.org) in order to retrieve the parents/ancestors and children/descendents of a giving GO id

I could retrieve the parents using the query:

```
{
  Class_GET_BY_ID(uris:[
    "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0032259",
    "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0007267"]) {
    id
    label
    subClassOf {
      id
      label
      subClassOf {
        id
        label
        subClassOf {
        ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I don't know how to do the same to extract the descendents.

The `schema.graphql`:

```
type __Context {
    Class:          _@href(iri: "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class")
    id:             _@href(iri: "http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#id")
    label:          _@href(iri: "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label")
    subClassOf:     _@href(iri: "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf")
}

type Class @service(id:"go-local") {
    id: [String] @service(id:"go-local")
    label: [String] @service(id:"go-local")
    subClassOf: [Class] @service(id:"go-local")
}
```

I know it depends on the fields defined in the ontology, for instance in the first query I used `subClassOf` to get the top level.

In [SPARQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL) we can get the parent like this:

```
GO:0000XYZ rdfs:subClassOf ?parent
```

And the child:

```
GO:0000XYZ ^rdfs:subClassOf ?child
# or
?child rdfs:subClassOf obo:GO_0000XYZ .
```

As you see we can get both just by switching the query, is there a way to do something similar using GraphQL ?

**EDIT To clarify my issue**

I'm aware that we have to explicitly specify the depth/number of levels we want to extract using GraphQL.

This limitation I'm facing here is not being able to go down through the tree as I can go up using `superClassOf`

For instance if we image that we have `superClassOf` field, we can do it this way:

```
{
  Class_GET_BY_ID(uris:["http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0032259"]) {
    id
    label
    superClassOf {
      id
      label
      superClassOf {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems logical though that this field doesn't exist since it isn't useful in case we're using SPARQL since we can easily go up and down using only `subClassOf` as shown in query above.

Comment: It seems this is not possible to emulate SPARQL property paths in GraphQL: https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/91. Enable inferencing in your triplestore.

Comment: Thank you @StanislavKralin for your reply, I checked out the github issue, it mainly discusses the possibility to get *all* the parent/children using recursive queries, in my question I don't have a problem with the depth, sorry maybe the last two SPARQL query were confusing, I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Ah, you are rather about `^` than `*`! OK.

Comment: @StanislavKralin, yes you're right.